# numpy one-liner for combining unequal length np.array to a matrix(or 2d array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of arrays of different length, I want to combine them to a matrix to largest dimension, and fill zeros at the ends. For example (pseudo-code):

```
combine( [1,2,3], [4,5]) 
[[1,2,3],[4,5,0]]
```

This is my current solution:

```
max_len = max(len(xx) for xx in X) 
M = np.array( [np.concatenate([xx, np.zeros( max_len - len(xx))]) for xx in X])
```

That's a lot to type for lazy person, is there a better solution?, any built-in functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.izip_longest()`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

import numpy as np

def mycombine(*args):
    return np.array(list(izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=0))).T
```

Comment: your method add a level of list .

Comment: @fasttooth without the list level you would not be able to build the array using the generator, so there is no reason for the downvote

Comment: yes, you are right. isn't a way to instantiate a generator without this 'list' side effect?